# Skip npm postinstall script in Travis

Tags: npm, continuous-integration, travis-ci, npm-install, npm-scripts

I have an app that deploys on **AWS** as well as **Cloud66**(for some reason). In order to build the app for aws, we have to write the script in `travis.yml` and to deploy to **Cloud66** we have to write the build commands in `postInstall`.

What happens is when travis is triggered, it does `npm install` for which it runs the postScript also which builds the application, also again in the yml script the app build is made. Thus there are two builds happening each time a change is triggered, which is unnecessary.

I tried to remove the postInstall script by adding an environment var in travis and running a preinstall script that will delete the postInstall script in the package. This deletes the postInstall script but it doesn't change anything, postInstall script somehow runs even then.

snippet of **package.json**

```
"preinstall": "node setEnvironment.js",
"postinstall": "npm run build-production"
```

snippet of **travis.yml**

```
script:
- if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "prod" ]; then npm run build-production && gulp
  copy-deploy-configs --type=prod; else echo "not an prod branch"; fi
```

**setEnvironment.js**

```
const package = require('./package.json');
const fs = require('fs');

const environment = process.env.APP_ENVIRONMENT;

if (environment === 'travis') {
    delete package.scripts.postinstall;
} else {
    package.scripts["postinstall"] = `npm run build-${environment}`;
}

fs.writeFileSync('package.json', JSON.stringify(package, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `package.json` you could do the following:

```
"postinstall": "if [ -z \"$TRAVIS_BRANCH\" ]; then npm run build-production; fi"
```

This should only be executed if `$TRAVIS_BRANCH` is not set, which should only happen on **Cloud66**.